# Add custom label with selected range

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I created a macro that creates a new line series named "pos" which is the datalabel postion of another line series within my selected chart.
The next move is to select a custom data label range to be applied in my "pos" series (which is the datalabel position only).

The following code is working

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").Select
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
        InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=Chart!$C$3:$C$28", 0
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.ShowValue = False
```

But if I want to select manually the range, there is an error.

```
Dim myrange As Range
Dim myrng As Range
Dim labelrange As Range
Set myrng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range", _
                                        Title:="Range", Type:=8)

myrange = myrng.Range.Address(True, True)
Set labelrange = ActiveSheet.Range(myrng)

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").Select
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, labelrange.Address(External:=True), 0
Selection.ShowRange = True
Selection.ShowValue = False
```

Comment: This line is problematic: `myrange = myrng.Range.Address(True, True)`. You are currently using `myrange` as a string variable, while you have dimmed it as `Range`. Which one is it? To me it is simply redundant: `myrng.Address` will do if you really are interested in the Address property. `.Range` is not a valid property of your returned range object meaning that will error out, also both row and column parameters are `TRUE` by default. I have not checked the rest of your code in detail but a note, `.Select`, `ActiveSheet` and the likes should be avoided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Almost there, but I got the answer thanks to you, the correct code is the following

```
Sub Definelabelasrangevalues()
Dim myrnglabel As Range
Dim labelrange As String
Dim mychart As Chart

Set myrnglabel = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range label", _
                                    Title:="Range label", Type:=8)
labelrange = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & myrnglabel.Address

Set mychart = ActiveChart
On Error GoTo Error
mychart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
mychart.FullSeriesCollection("Pos").ApplyDataLabels
mychart.SeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, labelrange, 0
mychart.SeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.ShowRange = True
mychart.SeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.ShowValue = False
mychart.SeriesCollection("Pos").DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove

Exit Sub
Error: MsgBox ("Select a chart first!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```
Dim myrange As String
Dim myrng As Range
Dim labelrange As String
Set myrng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range", _
                                    Title:="Range", Type:=8)

myrange = myrng.Address(True, True)
labelrange = myrange
```